# How to get "ID" of Login form username and password inputs?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

You know that ASP.NET generate two form input for username and password from `<asp:Login>`
I want to attach jQuery virtual keyboard to login inputs;to reaching this,I need know `ID` of generated html Login form inputs.How can I get those?

```
<asp:Login ID="myLogin" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a consistent naming convention, so you can use this selector to get to it:

```
jQuery("#<%= myLoginControl.ClientID %> input[id$='_UserName']").attr("id")

jQuery("#<%= myLoginControl.ClientID %> input[id$='_Password']").attr("id")
```

The `ClientID` of the `Login` control is the ID for the table which surrounds the contents, and the textboxes end with `_UserName` and `_Password`.